# How to search and replace using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Excel programming. Consider an Excel sheet with nxn values. My task is to search for text called "TOOTHBRUSH BATT" from A column. A column consists of multiple "TOOTHBRUSH " value.

Once the value is found suppose in cell A11 then I need to change text in D11 ie corresponding D column to "BATTERY". D11 will already have some text, I need to replace that text with "BATTERY"

My code is

```
Sub replacement()

    Dim S  As String
    Dim H  As String

    S = "TOOTHBRUSH BATT"

    For i = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Range("A" & i) = S Then
            Range("D" & i) = "BATTERY"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know vba well enough but if this is a one-time thing, you don't need vba for this?! Add a new column and paste all the values of your D column to it and replace the D column with a formula like `if(A1='TOOTBRUSH';'BATTERY', E1)`

Comment: What's wrong with your existing code?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: williams :        its not making any changes in my original file but if i am copying certain data starting from toothbrush batt and pasting it in other sheet than there it is woking

Comment: Please try to use informative titles for the benefit of future readers, and _really_ do leave out "urgent" and other forms of begging - all questions are of equal importance here.

Answer (score 0):

```
nRow = Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(What:="*TOOTHBRUSH BATT*", after:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

Worksheets(1).Cells(nRow,"D") = "BATTERY"
```

By using auto filter (below code not tested)

```
Worksheets(1).autofiltermode = false
Worksheets(1).Range("A:B").autofilter
Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*TOOTHBRUSH BATT*"

dim nRng as range

If Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
     set nRng  = Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Columns(2).Resize(Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     nRng.value = "BATTERY"
End If
```

Comment: if used above code then it will find only 1 st value and make change and stop..i have many TOOTHBRUSH BATT VALUES

Comment: in that case, you should try using auto filter. will be faster

Comment: although above code can be loop by adding some looping logic, but is not a fast way to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is Similar to Eric's Answer.

```
' Declare range  to set to the first cell we find
Dim find as Range
set find = Range("A:A").Cells.Find(What:="TOOTHBRUSH BATT")

' This is the cell Address (in case it keeps looping back to beginning)
Dim addy as string
if not find is nothing then addy = find.address

' If we've found a cell then Keep Do something with it
Do while not find is nothing
    find.Value = "BATTERY"


    ' Find the next Cell
    set find = Range("A:A").Cells.Find(What:="TOOTHBRUSH BATT", After:= find)
    ' If the next found cell is the first one then exit sub/function
    if find.address = addy then exit sub
Loop
```